# Is there a complete list of International(xlCountryCode) in Windows?

Tags: excel, vba, windows

I have a macro in Excel that saves the the Application.International(xlCountryCode) attribute when users run some code. But so far I haven't been able to identify all codes. I found a partial [list of languages][1], but I still don't know the majority of the codes.

This is the list I have received so far:

- 1 (US)
- 34 (Spanish)
- 44 (?)
- 51 (?)
- 52 (?)
- 54 (?)
- 56 (?)
- 57 (?)
- 595 (?)
- 598 (?)
- 800 (?)

Does anyone knows where can i find the remaining ones?

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you find those? how do you know that there is a 598 for example? It looks like you tried to provide a link, but it's not there in your question.

Comment: This is the best I can find, but it's not really what you are asking. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.international

Comment: I receive a log registry with some information (tool used, username, Excel version, and the country code). Mostly to track what tools are most used. The list I provided are the country codes I've received so far. Incredibly there's no explanation in any Microsoft site about the translation for those codes.

Answer (score 3):

The country code for Germany is 49, Philippines 63, China 86.
Find more codes in the [complete list](https://countrycode.org/)

Comment: Thank you! This is quite useful! I searched everywhere for the codes -- ISO, international conventions, etc.-- but none matched. This list is a salvation.

Comment: What on Earth, I'd never realised that the cryptic xlCountryCode is just... the international dialing code for phone calls?!

Comment: Not quite. `xlCountryCode` is a built-in enumeration with the value of 1 which specifies the first of Excel's *International* settings. `Application.International(xlCountryCode)` will indeed return the country code but only if you have set it up. I didn't and the function returns 1 on my PC. `Application.International(xlCountrySetting)` returns 44 on my PC, not because I reside in the UK but because I use UK English. It wasn't I but Excel (or Office or Windows) who volunteered that information.